# Выделение памяти для переменной внутри функции и передача уже выделенной памяти в функцию

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

1 вариант:

```
void func(int ** &arr, int size) {
    arr = new int * [size];
    <...>
}

int main() {
    int size = <...>;
    int **arr;

    func(arr, size);
}
```

2 вариант:

```
void func(int **arr, int size) {
   <...>
}

int main() {
    int size = <...>;
    int **arr = new int * [size];

    func(arr, size);
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в первом варианте мы в функции выделяем память под массив и передаем `arr` по ссылке, а во втором варианте в `main` выделяем память и тогда уже не надо по ссылке в функцию передавать `arr`. Не понимаю, как тут работают указатели.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае мы объявляем переменную `arr` типа `int **`. Передаем ссылку на нее в функцию `func` и уже там присваиваем ей значение.

Во втором случае мы объявляем переменную `arr` типа `int **` и *сразу* присваиваем ей значение — указатель на выделенную память.

Таким и образом, и первый и второй вариант код верный. Какой именно способ использовать зависит от ваших предпочтений и, собственно, решаемой этим кодом задачи.

> …и тогда уже не надо по ссылке в функцию передавать `arr`…

В первом случае мы могли бы воспользоваться указателем, а не ссылкой:

```
void func(int ***arr, size_t size) {
    *arr = new int * [size];
    <...>
}
```

Однако никто не мешает вам и во втором случае передавать `arr` по ссылке.

Comment: void func(int*** arr, int size)
{
 *arr = new int*[size];
}

void main()
{
 int size;
 int** arr;
 func(&arr, size);
} Почему тут 3 указателя ?

Comment: @Aaas `*arr = ...`

Comment: @Aaas, потому что мы должны передать адрес переменной `arr` из функции `main`, чтобы могли поменять именно ее (используя этот адрес), а не локальную копию этой переменной в функции `func`.

Answer (score 1):

Никто не мешает в первом случае тоже выделять память в `main`. Но вот во втором случае выделять память в `func` не получится.

Смотрите, совсем простой пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    foo(y);
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Что напечатает этот код, `1`? Нет, `0`, потому что `x` и `y` - разные переменные. А если сделать `void foo(int &x)`, тогда результат будет `1`.

С указателями то же самое.

Если вы внутри `void func(int **arr, int size)` сделаете `arr = new ...`, то переменная `int **arr` в `main` не изменится, и из `main` вы никак не получите доступ к этой памяти.

Однако! Если вы меняете `arr[i]` или `*arr`, то эти изменения в любом случае будут видны снаружи функции. При передаче `arr` из `main` в `void func(int **arr, int size)`, копируется только сам указатель, но не то, на что он указывает (т.е. копируется адрес, записанный в указателе). То есть изменения самого указателя не будут заметны снаружи функции, в отличие от изменений того, на что он указывает.